# MySQL 'IS NULL' sets the values to NULL in a JOIN query

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two tables: PlayerAchievements and AchievedAchievements. I want to join these tables and check if the right table (The achievements the player has achieved) is NULL, meaning the obvious that the player has not yet received that achievement:

```
SELECT achievement
     , achieved 
  FROM 
     ( PlayerAchieved 
  LEFT 
  JOIN AchievedAchievemnts 
    ON AchievedAchievements IS NULL
     );
```

The issue is that if I just check the tables doing something like:

```
SELECT p.achievementname
     , a.achievementname
     , achieved 
  FROM 
     ( PlayerAchieved p
  LEFT 
  JOIN AchievedAchievements a
    ON p.achievementname = a.achievementname
     );
```

Gives me what I expect:

```
achievementname achievementname achieved
=============== =============== ========
First Kill      First Kill      1
Monster Kill    Monster Kill    NULL
...
```

But when I do

```
SELECT PlayerAchieved.achievementname, AchievedAchievments.achievementname, achieved FROM (PlayerAchieved LEFT OUTER JOIN AchievedAchievements ON PlayerAchieved.achievementname = AchievedAchievments.achievementname AND achieved IS NULL);
```

I get

```
achievementname achievementname achieved
=============== =============== ========
First Kill      First Kill      NULL
Monster Kill    Monster Kill    NULL
...
```

and everything becomes NULL. Why does everything become NULL from nowhere?

Comment: You have a column called AchievedAchievemnts in a table called AchievedAchievemnts ?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to write this:

```
SELECT      achievement,
            achieved
FROM        PlayerAchieved
LEFT JOIN   AchievedAchievemnts
    ON      AchievedAchievments.achievementname = PlayerAchieved.achievementname
WHERE       AchievedAchievments.achievementname IS NULL
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of why the last query never joins?

Comment: Yes this is the "correct way" but why does my version not work? Why is "where" different from "AND" here?

Comment: LEFT JOIN conditions apply only for the "successful" joining, if you want to tell if a row found a matching join, you should put it in the WHERE clause